# Forced vibration second order differential equation using python

Tags: python, math, differential-equations, vibration, runge-kutta

I want to make a modification to the example shown here [link](https://perso.crans.org/besson/notebooks/Runge-Kutta_methods_for_ODE_integration_in_Python.html) by adding a force to the right-hand side of the equation such as u(t), where u(t) is read from a text file. The original equation is θ′′(t)+bθ′(t)+csin(θ(t))=0 and the new equation is θ′′(t)+bθ′(t)+csin(θ(t))=u(t). Could you give some suggestions or let me know where I can find examples?

The original code for the original equation is the following

```
def pend(y, t, b, c):
return np.array([y[1], -b*y[1] - c*np.sin(y[0])])

b = 0.25
c = 5.0
y0 = np.array([np.pi - 0.1, 0.0])
#if I just add a parameter u(t) here, it didn't work

def rungekutta4(f, y0, t, args=()):
n = len(t)
y = np.zeros((n, len(y0)))
y[0] = y0
for i in range(n - 1):
    h = t[i+1] - t[i]
    k1 = f(y[i], t[i], *args)
    k2 = f(y[i] + k1 * h / 2., t[i] + h / 2., *args)
    k3 = f(y[i] + k2 * h / 2., t[i] + h / 2., *args)
    k4 = f(y[i] + k3 * h, t[i] + h, *args)
    y[i+1] = y[i] + (h / 6.) * (k1 + 2*k2 + 2*k3 + k4)
return y
```

Comment: Following the steps of the derivation in the link you provided, the additional u(t) term will appear in the second component of your `pend` function. Given that you want it to be read from a file, I assume it is discrete data, meaning you will need to interpolate it using e.g. `scipy.interpolate.interp1d`.

Comment: Thanks Peter. It doesn't seem to allow me to make u(t) as a parameter like t. I tried def peng(y, u(t), p, alpha, E, A, m, F) but this didn't work. Could you give more hints?

Comment: Given the structure of your Runge-Kutta solver, it requires `pend(y, t, ...)`, the `y` and `t` must not change position, any other inputs required for `pend` go into the `args`. After importing your data and interpolation, you get a `function` `u` with one input, `t`. Now, you would redefine `pend` to `pend(y, t, b, c, u)` and add an evaluation of `u(t)` in the return of `pend` at the appropriate place. Finally, you call `rungekutta4(pend, y0, t, b, c, u)`.